# How can I get NAICS (or SICS) data for the 6000+ stocks on the NYSE?

Tags: data

I have had no problem getting a CSV file with the 6000 or so NYSE stocks, but it just has the stock symbol and the market capitalization.

How can I get the NAICS (or SICS) code for the companies listed on the NYSE?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the cik of the stock you can scrape them from the sec's website

This is a sample filing for apple cik : 320193

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/0000320193-20-000096.hdr.sgml

The tag you are looking for is ASSIGNED-SIC

The directories are open for search so just pick any filing at https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193 or the cik of your choice

If you want sics for 6000 stocks you will have to make 6000*3 requests to the sec so you better wait between requests.

Once you have SICs you can easily map them to NAICS:
https://www.naics.com/sic-naics-crosswalk-search-results/

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood by paying a vendor.  SIC is a proprietary classification, it's owner isn't likely giving them away for free.

The search function on the SIC website does return SIC code for searched on securities though, so you may be able to write something to do a bulk search and store them yourself.

https://siccode.com/business/amazon-com-inc

Also, for ref, SIC isn't a common sector classification...GICS and ICB are more standard.

Comment: The main question is about NAICS. The SICS was just listed as a secondary alternative, so this is not really responsive to the question and more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @TylerDurden, The answer is pay for it.  There's a data source thread on here if you search for it that may be useful to you, but barring a handful of exceptions, data isn't free.  Businesses are built on data licensing, the idea that someone somewhere has the data you want and is offering it for free doesn't make much sense (it cost them something to collect or aggregate it, whether time or money).